# Inclusion - exclusion riddle [Full answer provided] - Need an explanation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

> 2n Clowns are sitting in a carouse. Each of them sees exactly one clown
> in front of him. In how many ways they can swap places so each one
> will see a **new** clown in front of him if the places are marked?

**Answer:**

$|U|= (2n)!$ are all the possibilities

We define sets:

A1 - group of all options from U where pair # 1 is facing each other

A2 - group of all options from U where pair # 2 is facing each other

.

.

An -  group of all options from U where pair # n is facing each other

$|\bar{A_{1}}\cap \bar{A_{2}}\cap..\cap\bar{A_{n}} |$

According to the principle of exclusion and inclusion we will get

[image]

[image]

---

- Can I get more elaboration on the answer?
- What does $\bar{A}$ mean in term of the definition of $A$ above?
- What does $|\bar{A_{1}}\cap \bar{A_{2}} |$ mean in term of the
  definition?
- What are the all options for example for group A1 that is defined
  above, how is calculated combinatory?

Comment: $\overline{A}$  denotes the complement of $A$ here.

Comment: @drhab I know, i asked what does it mean in the terms of the definition of A? is it like $\bar{A}$ is the group of options where pair aren't facing each other?

Comment: Yes, it indeed does.

Comment: @drhab we why want to know the the group of options where pair aren't facing each other?

Comment: Do you agree with the general formula $|U|= (2n)!$ ? Try with $n=2$, i.e. $2$ pairs i.e. $4$ clown on two rows. We have the total possible moves are $4 \times 3 \times 2= 24= (2 \times 2 )!$

Comment: We can check that, with $n=2$ we have (I hope I've made the correct computation) $4$ possible moves that satisfy the condition that "group of all options from U where pair # 1 is facing each other". Let row 1: A and C and row 2: B and D with pair #1 is A-B. We can 1) swap A with B, 2) swap A with B and C with D, 3) swap A with C and B with D, 4) swap A with D and B with C. If so $|A_1|=4$ and $|\overline {A_1}|=20$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But according to the answer group A1 has 2n(2n−2)! ways, so if n=2 then there are 8 ways

Answer (score 0):

$\bar A_i$ means here the complement of $A$, i.e. group of all options from $U$ where pair #$i$ is **not** facing each other.

$|\bar{A_{1}}\cap \bar{A_{2}} |$ means here the **number** of all options from $U$ where neither pair # 1 nor pair # 2 are facing each other.

The number of all options in $A_1$ is $2n(2n-2)!$ where the factor $2n$ counts the number of ways to choose the cabin and places in the cabin for the pair #1, whereas the other clowns can choose their places arbitrarily in $(2n-2)!$ ways.

Similarly $|{A_{1}}\cap{A_{2}} |=2^2n(n-1)(2n-4)!$ and so on. The final formula is the [special case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#A_special_case) application of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Why the minus 2 in (2n-2)! ?

Comment: @Mostfashma There were $2n$ clowns. You found two  places for two of them. How many clowns (places) remain?

Comment: We subtract because it’s a circular combination?

Comment: Since circular combination is when n people sitting in circle and there are (n-1)! Ways to do it

Comment: To your question yes 2n-2 places left, I’m just trying to figure out why we included the subtract

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "we included the subtract".

Comment: What’s the difference between (2n)! And (2n-2)! For the question?

Comment: The difference is $(2n)!-(2n-2)! $ independent of the context.

Comment: No I meant what are the differences in terms of meaning? I know that (2n)! are number of ways to rearrange 2n clowns correct?

Comment: We have already arranged two of them. How many clowns remain to arrange?

Comment: What I don't understand is the concept of pairs, if we have $n=2$, 4 clowns {A,B,C,D} thus we have different 6 pairs? such that (A,B) (A,C) (A,D) (B,C) (B,D) (C,D) ? which isn't the case according to the answer since it says there are $n$ number of pairs

Comment: A pair consists of two clowns initially facing each other. Is this the only thing which you still don't understand?

Comment: Yes I can't seem to figure it out what I'm thinking is for example A1 is where pairs A&B always facing each other and A2 where A&C Always facing each other etc.. but obviously its not the concept according to the answer, could you give me a numeric example of all pairs from 1 to $n$ where $n=2$?

Comment: $(1,2), (3,4)$.